# Which of these ways is more plausible to prove that $c0=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading Lang's *Linear Algebra* and trying to prove that $c0=0$ with the axioms given in $EV1-EV8$. I initially thought the proof was:

$$ c0\stackrel{?}{=}0 \\ c(A-A)\stackrel{?}{=}0\\ cA-cA\stackrel{?}{=}0$$

And from here I guess one could see that the relationship of inverseness would be preserved (by subtracting the inverse of $-cA$ from both sides?). Later, I thought about the following:

$$ c0\stackrel{?}{=}0 \\ \cfrac{1}{c}\cdot c0\stackrel{?}{=}\cfrac{1}{c} 0 \\ 1\cdot0\stackrel{?}{=}\cfrac{1}{c} 0 $$

And using that $1\cdot u=u$:

$$0\stackrel{?}{=}\cfrac{1}{c} 0 $$

But I guess I would be unable to cancel $1/c$ on the other side. I'm a bit confused, none of these proofs seems finished to me. The first one doesn't seems to come to a conclusion and the second one doesn't seems to use the axioms for vector spaces, they seem more to use the axioms for fields. I tried to do something which almost worked:

$$c0\stackrel{?}{=}0\\ (1+1+1+\dots + 1)0\stackrel{?}{=}0 \\1\cdot 0+1\cdot 0 + \dots + 1\cdot 0\stackrel{?}{=}0\\0+0+0+\dots + 0\stackrel{!}{=}0$$

But I noticed that if $c>\lfloor c \rfloor$ then I guess it wouldn't prove it totaly, because:

$$ 1\cdot 0+1\cdot 0 + \dots + 1\cdot 0+ (c-\lfloor c\rfloor)0\stackrel{?}{=}0\\0+0+0+\dots + (c-\lfloor c\rfloor)0\stackrel{?}{=}0 \\ (c-\lfloor c\rfloor)0\stackrel{?}{=}0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider starting from $0 + 0  = 0$ (because $0$ is the additive identity). Multiply both sides by $c$. Then do some cancelling. :)